# Upload project edits to new git branch

Tags: git, github

I do have a project that was once cloned from github repository, but the .git folder itself was later deleted. So I did `init a new git` and `added remote origin` for it (to the one it was cloned from)

Can you please explain the proper way to push the new edits to the new branch and leave remote master branch untouched?

P.S: I'll do appreciate and accept some articles that describe similar process

Comment: Probably re-clone and copy the .git folder to your old copy? The `git init` way will probably not work unless you want to force push and lose all history.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, It actually appeared not so hard. git init > set remote origin > add & commit to master > create new branch > push to origin newBranch

Comment: But you wont be able to merge them without jumping though hoops. Since they share no history. That's solvable too though I suppose.

Comment: @OliviaRuth will keep trying if some solution exists will come back with an update.

Comment: Do a fresh clone to have the correct history, then cp all the files from your first clone to this new one to have the diff. As it, you can do the commit based on the remote state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new clone approach is easier:

```
git clone /url/remote/repo
cd repo
git checkout -b newBranch
```

Here comes the tip to quickly integrate your existing files

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/your/old/files add .
git commit -m "Import existing files"
```

Finally

```
git push -u origin newBranch
```